# Not able to do Sendkeys() in Username box. It shows Elementnotinteractable Exception using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

In Registration Form, Trying to enter text in username text box using sendkeys(). But it throws ElementNotInteractable Exception. Then i used implicit wait and webdriverwait to find that element , it also throwed be Timeout Exception. Kindly suggest a solutions for this, as i am not able to proceed for here. Used selenium Webdriver with java.

here is the [site](http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php) used

[Attached the DOM tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVzIF.png)

Code Below:

```
@Test
public void regform() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    RemoteWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.get("http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php");
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
    WebElement usrname = d.findElementByXPath("//input[@name='username']");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(usrname));
    usrname.sendKeys("User1");
    d.close();
}
```

Console Log:

```
FAILED: regform
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (12e645803db8e870be7722d06896cc88)] -> xpath: //input[@name='username']] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-O0V8JPK', ip: '192.168.1.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Shamili\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61086}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 12e645803db8e870be7722d06896cc88
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at basicautomationconcepts.RegistrationForm.regform(RegistrationForm.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you try to automate contains two similar forms, hence there are two elements within the DOM that match your XPath. The first one is not displayed and thus not interactable. That is why you got `ElementNotInteractableException`, and that is why you get `TimeoutException` trying to wait until it became visible.

Changing your xpath to `"(//input[@name='username'])[2]"` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. After changing the xpath as @yevhen Danchenko said it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with the below xpath. It worked for me.

```
"//*[@id=\"load_form\"]/fieldset[6]/input"
```